# How to pass a variable in a function call

Tags: php, function, email

Please i need a help with my code, am trying to send a mail with this function but it's failing to send a mail. Please i will appreciate it if some help me look at the entire code base and correct the errors.  Thanks.

**emailClass.php**

```
<?php

class email
{
function emailWithAttach($fromaddress, $toAddress, $mailSubject, $mailMessageHead, $mailMessageMain, $mailMessageEnd, $fileName)
{
    $fileatt_name = "Invoice";
    $fileatt = $fileName;
    $fileatt_type = "application/octet-stream";
    $email_from = $fromaddress;
    $email_subject = $mailSubject;

    $email_message = $mailMessageHead."<br>";
    $email_message .= $mailMessageMain."<br>";
    $email_message .= $mailMessageEnd;

    $email_to = $toAddress;
    $headers = "From: ".$email_from;

    $file = fopen($fileatt, 'rb');
    $data = fread($file, filesize($fileatt));
    fclose($file);

    $semi_rand=md5(time());
    $mime_boundary .= "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version:1.0\n".
    "Content-Type: Multipart/mixed;\n".
    "boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n".
    "--{$mime_boundary}\n".
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n".
    $email_message .= "\n\n";

    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

    $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n".
    "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n".
    "name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n".
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n".
    $data .="\n\n".
    "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

    if(mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
    {
        return true;
    }

}
}


?>
```

This is my template **index.php**

```
<?php
include "emailClass.php";

$testEmail = new email();
$from = 'chidiebere.ezeka@yahoo.com';
$sendTo = 'chidiebere.ezeka@gmail.com';
$subject ='ABS Travels';
$bodyHead = 'Welcome to attachment of Email';
$bodyMain = 'I love the way php handles email attachment, it is amazing to me';
$bodyEnd = 'Thank you';
//$filePath = '';
$fileName = 'reports.pdf';

if($testEmail->emailWithAttach($from, $sendTo, $subject, $bodyHead, $bodyMain, $bodyEnd, $fileName))
{
    echo 'Email send successful';
}
else
{
    echo 'Email Failed';
}
?>
```

I have updated my code with the corrections made, yet the mail is not sending.  please any suggestion..it doesn't display any error apart from "Email Failed" message.

Comment: Sorry, but questions just asking "my code does not work, please fix it" are clearly considered off-topic here. You want to look for a (payed) programmer to do your work for you. We are here to help, but for that you need to 1. be willing to debug yourself, 2. tell us what exactly the issue is.

Comment: What is the output of ```$testEmail->emailWithAttach()``` . ?

Comment: One hint: turn or error logging, remove that `@` from the `@mail(...)` call and start monitoring your http servers error log file. It will probably tell you the specific issue _if_ the issue is within your code. If you are programming in php in a web environment you won't get around monitoring that error log file. Working without is like flying in a dark cave with your eyes blind folded...

Answer (score 0):

Fix typo and it should work!

```
<?php
[...]

$testEmail = new email(); # When you call a new class you need the parenthese 
[...]
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..i have done that yet the Email failed message still persist..